# Sharing form input values from one JSP page to another using JavaBeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I'm quite new to JSPs and JavaBeans and trying out how to pass values of parameters from a form in one JSP (theForm.jsp) to another JSP (theResult.jsp) as follows:

In my `theResult.jsp`:

```
<body>
   <jsp:useBean id="user" class="people.User" scope="application"/>

   Your username is:  <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="username"/><br>
   Your password is:  <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="password"/><br>
</body>
```

And in my `theForm.jsp` file:

```
<body>
   <jsp:useBean id="user" class="people.User" scope="application">
      <jsp:setProperty name="user" property="username" value='<%=request.getParameter("username")%>'/>
      <jsp:setProperty name="user" property="password" param="password"/>  // another way to use setProperty, I read
    </jsp:useBean>


   <form action="theResult.jsp" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Type your username"><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Type your password"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
</body>
```

But all my result is showing is:

**Your username is:  null

Your password is:  null**

My `people.user` javabean:

```
package people;

public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;


    public User(){}

    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }

    //... and same thing for 'password'
```

}

Comment: Your request parameters *when you load the form page* are null. This appears to be doing what it should.

Comment: So, any suggestions as to how can I actually start to fix it or....?

Comment: I see that you're doing this to learn to use beans, but this is a use case that absolutely doesn't need them. `theResult.jsp` can just read the values out of the request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
   <jsp:useBean id="user" class="people.User"/>
   <jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/>
   <%-- the (*) symbol indicates the value should come
        from request parameter whose name matches property
        name . Thus simple automatic conversion should be
        performed --%/>
   Your username is: <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="username"/><br>
   Your password is: <jsp:getProperty name="password"/><br>
```